# why R does not provide information as much as gdalinfo?

Tags: r, netcdf

I opened a netCDF file in `R` and looked at the header information. Afterwards I used `gdalinfo` to look at the header information of the same file.

What I found is that there are much-much more information shown by the `gdalinfo` (time  origin , units , etc.). Is there a command to grasp more information of a variable in netCDF file with `R`?

```
             f=open.ncdf("C:\\BR_Ban.nc")

              > f
            [1] "file C:\\GF_Guy_6Y.nc has 4 dimensions:"
              [1] "x   Size: 1"
              [1] "y   Size: 1"
              [1] "land   Size: 1"
           [1] "tstep   Size: 105120"
       [1] "double nav_lon[x,y]  Longname:Longitude Missval:1e+30"
       [1] "double nav_lat[x,y]  Longname:Latitude Missval:1e+30"
       [1] "float time[tstep]  Longname:Time axis Missval:1e+30"
     [1] "float timestp[tstep]  Longname:Time step axis Missval:1e+30"

Then read one variable

           A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="time",verbose=TRUE)
     [1] "vobjtodimname: is a character type varid.  This file has 6 dims"
    [1] "vobjtodimname: no cases found, returning FALSE"
     [1] "get.var.ncdf: isdimvar: FALSE"
      [1] "vobjtovarid: entering with varid=date"
     [1] "Variable named date found in file with varid= 7"
     [1] "vobjtovarid: returning with varid deduced from name; varid= 7"
    [1] "get.var.ncdf: ending up using varid= 7"
     [1] "ndims: 2"
  [1] "get.var.ncdf: varsize:"
    [1]     3 52560
     [1] "get.var.ncdf: start:"
     [1] 1 1
      [1] "get.var.ncdf: count:"
    [1]     3 52560
     [1] "get.var.ncdf: totvarsize: 157680"
     [1] "Getting var of type 3  (1=short, 2=int, 3=float, 4=double, 5=char, 6=byte)"
    [1] "get.var.ncdf: C call returned 0"
    [1] "count.nodegen: 3    Length of data: 157680"     "count.nodegen: 52560    Length of data: 157680"
     [1] "get.var.ncdf: final dims of returned array:"
        [1]     3 52560
```

Comment: Your post is missing some rather important information (i.e., how did you read-in the NetCDF data). The rgdal package supports this format and also has the GDALinfo command available. I have not idea why somebody would want all of this information echoed during read or summary. I agree that R spamming me with this would drive me nuts. I would also add that if you read the data in via the raster package, which is a memory safe option, that this information is displayed in the raster summary.

Comment: To run gdalinfo from within R, take a look at `system`.

Comment: `system` is an R command, look at `?system`.

Comment: You don't need to use system. The function is built into the rgdal package. Use require(rgdal) to add the library and then bring up help using ?GDALinfo. You can display info without even reading in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, because `gdalinfo` is a program for displaying information about a particular type of data sets, while R is a language designed to analyze all kinds of data sets. If R spammed me with such information every time I import a data set, I would quickly go nuts.

Of course, this information can be accessed in R, you just need to ask for it.

```
class( f )
dim( f )
summary( f )
plot( f )
```

Comment: The units can be accessed if they are present in the netcdf file. Please make your question more specfic, what do you need what ncdf does not provide.